# Why cannot anonymous users vote, even though they have permission for it?

Tags: 7, rating

I installed the [Fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar) module and added the *Stars (rated while viewing)* field in a content type.

I gave to the *rate content* permission anonymous users. They can see all the content and the voting widget, but they can't vote. Why?

Comment: So does clicking a star rating trigger some AJAX or other JS error?

Comment: @ShawnConn no nothing. i used diffchecker and the markup is identical. really strange

Comment: There are settings for how many times you can vote in voting API module admin/config/search/votingapi check there for the amount of time that must pass before two anonymous vote. If you are testing functionality it could be from there

Answer (score 0):

A possible explanation for this might be what is described in this issue on D.O: [Fivestar Not Working for Anonymous Users with Cache Enabled](https://www.drupal.org/node/2297231).

A possible workaround for it is mentioned in [Comment #9](https://www.drupal.org/node/2297231#comment-9315585) of that issue, which states:

> ... When I set the author to anonymous on the field also set the field to allow users to vote on their own content, this appears to work as a crude work around.

Curious to hear if this somehow helps ...